# How to convert a sequence of registered RGB and depth images into a ROSBAG?

Tags: slam, navigation, rosbag, rgbd, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to use the rgbdslam_v2 package http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/ on my own RGB-D data.

My RGB-D data is supplied as a a pair of image sequences, one consisting of depth images and the other one containing the corresponding registered rgb data.

Does anybody please know how to convert this pair of image streams into a rosbag file that could be subsequently used by rgbdslam_v2? The depth camera intrinsics are known ...

Thanks a lot
David

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254964/how-to-convert-a-sequence-of-registered-rgb-and-depth-images-into-a-rosbag?/) by [davnov134](https://answers.ros.org/users/29396/davnov134/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag offers APIs for C++ and Python: [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) which makes it really easy to put your messages into a bag file.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2017-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-18**:
@davnov134: take a look at #q233042 as well. Perhaps the script that @Martin Günther wrote can help / provide some inspiration.